# Inno Setup: Hide the filenames while installing

Tags: file, hide

I'm struggling to find the configuration in the inno script to hide the extracted files while installing. The default setup will show which files have been extracted to the selected folder. Any helps ? Thanks.

http://58.26.233.102/webupdate/hide.jpg

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116109/918626

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inno Setup - How to create a personalized FilenameLabel with the names I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748508/inno-setup-how-to-create-a-personalized-filenamelabel-with-the-names-i-want)