# Hide the file names from the Inno Setup progress page

Tags: inno-setup

How can I hide or remove the names of files being installed from the label above the installation progress bar leaving only "ex: install"?

It appears as the files are being unpacked.

[image: Screenshot of the Inno Setup installation progress page]

```pascal
LabelCurrFileName.Caption :=
  ExpandConstant('{cm:ExtractedFile} ') + 
  MinimizePathName(
    CurrentFile, LabelCurrFileName.Font, LabelCurrFileName.Width - ScaleX(100));

LabelCurrFileName.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:ExtractedFile} ');
```

Comment: Could you post an English screenshot of the same screen, please ? Also, what version of InnoSetup are you using ? Could you include it into your question as well ? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inno Setup - How to create a personalized FilenameLabel with the names I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748508/inno-setup-how-to-create-a-personalized-filenamelabel-with-the-names-i-want)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want to replace the [`FilenameLabel`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm) label with your custom one. How to specify custom texts for different languages and how to use them with a custom label, that will be placed instead of [`FilenameLabel`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm) label you can find in the following script:

```pascal
[Languages]
Name: en; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: br; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"

[CustomMessages]
en.InstallingLabel=Installing...
br.InstallingLabel=Instalando...

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  with TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm) do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Parent;
    Left := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Left;
    Top := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Top;
    Width := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width;
    Height := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Height;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallingLabel}');
  end;
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```

---

@MartinPrikryl edit: For a complete implementation, see [Inno Setup - How to create a personalized FilenameLabel with the names I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43748508/850848)