# Inno Setup - How to hide certain filenames while installing? (FilenameLabel)

Tags: inno-setup

I want to hide certain filenames (not all) while installing (`FilenameLabel`).

I saw this [Hide the file names from the Inno Setup progress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115878/hide-the-file-names-from-the-inno-setup-progress-page/13116109#13116109). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options you have:

1. The only sure solution is to avoid installing the files, you do not want to show, using the `[Files]` section. Install them using a code instead. Use the [`ExtractTemporaryFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile) and [`FileCopy`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filecopy) functions.

   For an example of implementation, see:

   - [Install file in Inno Setup Pascal code using FileCopy function (not to show the installation on wizard form)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43669090/850848) or
   - [Inno Setup - Avoid displaying filenames of sub-installers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42531125/850848).
2. Or hide the files, you do not want to show, from the `FilenameLabel` in the `CurInstallProgressChanged`. Though that still likely displays the name briefly.
3. Or hide the actual label and create a custom one, as shown in the [Hide the file names from the Inno Setup progress page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13115878/850848). In the `CurInstallProgressChanged`, copy the files name, you *want to show* from the hidden to the custom label.

   See [Inno Setup - How to create a personalized FilenameLabel with the names I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43748508/850848)