# How to run an application with admin privileges from Inno Setup installer is set to PrivilegesRequired=lowest?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, elevated-privileges

I want to run the setup with `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`. How to set and run an application (dxwebsetup.exe) to install with my setup with Administrator privileges?

My code ([Inno Setup - Avoid displaying filenames of sub-installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531125/inno-setup-avoid-displaying-filenames-of-sub-installers)):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    if IsComponentSelected('DirectX') then
    begin
      ProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('Installing prerequsities', '');
      ProgressPage.SetText('Installing DirectX...', '');
      ProgressPage.Show;
      try
        ExtractTemporaryFile('dxwebsetup.exe');
        StartWaitingForDirectXWindow;
        Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\_Redist\dxwebsetup.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
             ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      finally
        StopWaitingForDirectXWindow;
        ProgressPage.Hide;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ShellExec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec) with `runas` verb, instead of `Exec`:

```pascal
ShellExec(
  'runas', ExpandConstant('{src}\_Redist\dxwebsetup.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
  ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

When the current Inno Setup process runs without Administrator privileges, you will get a UAC prompt.

---

It's also doable from the `[Run]` section:
[Execute postinstall program (sub installer) with administrator privileges in Inno Setup even if the main installer does not have them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74125021/850848)