# Test if Inno Setup installer is running with Administrator privileges

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, elevated-privileges

I want to run the installer in non-admin mode. However, when some driver is missing I wish to install it. Since change directive value from `[Code]` isn't possible, I was thinking if I can get the current mode of execution then I build my logic.

```pascal
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=lowest

[Code]

function IsKvaserNotInstalled: boolean;
begin
  Result := Not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'driver path');
end;

function MyConst(): String;
begin
  Result := '{#SetupSetting("PrivilegesRequired")}';
  MsgBox(Result, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MyConst();
  if IsKvaserNotInstalled() then begin
    MsgBox('KVASER driver is not installed. ' +
           'We require setup to run in admin mode to install it.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := false;
  end else
    Result := true;   
end;

function IsKvaserNotInstalled: boolean;
begin
  result := Not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    'SOFTWARE\KVASER AB\CANDriver 1.0\Drivers\kcanv');
end;

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\drivers_setup.exe"; Parameters: "/S" ; Check: IsKvaserNotInstalled;
```

`MyConst()` returns the value that is given `[Setup]` section. But I wish to get the value that indicates that the exe is currently running in admin mode. If I get a different value then, I can add it to if clause and continue the setup.

This won't work as because I need a silent installation:
[Inno Setup - How to run an aplication with admin privileges if the setup is set to PrivilegesRequired=lowest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566747/inno-setup-how-to-run-an-aplication-with-admin-privileges-if-the-setup-is-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if the installer is running with Administrator privileges, use [`IsAdmin` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmin).

Though, make sure you understand that there's difference between running installer with "administrator privileges" and running installer in "administrator mode". See also the answer by @Vinko.

Answer (score 1):

If your installation script is offering the User a choice between Admin and Non-Admin installation (see Inno Setup directives [`PrivilegesRequired`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) and [`PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequiredoverridesallowed)) then you might want to call the function [`IsAdminInstallMode()`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode) to check which choice was made.