# Bring Inno Setup installer to the foreground

Tags: inno-setup

How to bring the installer to the foreground at every progress page? (Assuming that the person installing the program decides to do other things with the computer in the meantime).

I am using this code to install DirectX and redist:
[Inno Setup - Avoid displaying filenames of sub-installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531125/inno-setup-avoid-displaying-filenames-of-sub-installers/42531358#42531358)
(look only the part that includes this `ProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage`).

Answer (score 2):

Do not even try this. That ruins user experience.

And Windows actually prevents you from doing that anyway.

If you need to bring user attention to your installer/application, flash its taskbar button.