# Install file in Inno Setup Pascal code using FileCopy function (not to show the installation on wizard form)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to copy a file using `FileCopy` function to the application folder, so that it's name does not display on the installing page? (`FilenameLabel`).

I.e. I want to use the first option of [Inno Setup - How to hide certain filenames while installing? (FilenameLabel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448959/inno-setup-how-to-hide-certain-filenames-while-installing-filenamelabel)

Comment: So why are you asking, if you already have an answer?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I do not know how to use the filecopy function.

Comment: And where does your question say that?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Edited...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`FileCopy` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filecopy) in the [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  { Install after installation, as then the application folder exists already }
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('Installing file');
    ExtractTemporaryFile('MyProg.exe');
    if FileCopy(
         ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyProg.exe'), ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.exe'),
         False) then
    begin
      Log('File installed.');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Failed to install file.');
    end;
  end;
end;
```