# Hide from a user, where files are being installed to, in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

This isn't about file visibility (hidden files vs whatever); this is about, what the user sees, while the installer is running.

Within the `Files` section of my script, I have the following

```
[Files]
Source: "02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627\*"; \
    DestDir: "{localappdata}\02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627"; \
    Flags: recursesubdirs onlyifdoesntexist
```

(Nothing malicious; just various program-necessary files and application configuration files).

I don't want the user to be able to see where these files are going when the installer is running. How can I configure Inno Setup so that it doesn't show the user when (and to where) these files are being installed?

**EDIT:**

I have accepted the answer below, but in case the links are deprecated ( and to shorten the trip of anyone who wants to do what I needed to do ), I have included an abridged version here. What I wanted to do ( while not knowing exactly how to word it ) was to hide the files being installed within the "installing" page.

To do that, add the following to the INNO script under the Code section -

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: There's no general solution to this. You need to hide the path from all places one by one. So what places do concern you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of places, where the path shows.

To hide the most prominent ones, do:

- *"Select Destination Location"* page – Just hide the page with using [`DisableDirPage` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage):

  ```
  [Setup]
  DisableDirPage=yes
  ```
- *"Installing"* page – See

  - [Hide the file names from the Inno Setup progress page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13115878/850848)
  - [Inno Setup - How to hide certain filenames while installing? (FilenameLabel)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42448959/850848)
  - [Inno Setup - Avoid displaying filenames of sub-installers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42531125/850848)
  - [Inno Setup - How to create a personalized FilenameLabel with the names I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43748508/850848)
- *"Ready to install"* page – If `DisableDirPage` is `yes` as shown above and [`AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_alwaysshowdironreadypage) has its default `no` value, the path won't show on this page.

  ```
  [Setup]
  DisableDirPage=yes
  AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage=no
  ```

Comment: Since this is just a wrapper for a VIsual Studio Setup and Deployment project, no actual installation takes place ( INNO installs the config settings for no real reason other than convenience ). INNO extracts the application installer to a temporary directory, and the runs it, so number 2 - the Installing page looks like the ticket.