# Inno Setup - How to create a personalized FilenameLabel with the names I want?

Tags: inno-setup

How to create a personalized `FilenameLabel` with the names I want? How to implement the suggestion from [Inno Setup - How to hide certain filenames while installing? (FilenameLabel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448959/inno-setup-how-to-hide-certain-filenames-while-installing-filenamelabel)  (third option, CurInstallProgressChanged, copy the files name, you want to show from the hidden to the custom label¨).

I see this code:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  with TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm) do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Parent;
    Left := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Left;
    Top := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Top;
    Width := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width;
    Height := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Height;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallingLabel}');
  end;
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```

But, how to define, if is possible, the names of files that i want with `CurInstallProgressChanged`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the answer you've linked:

- create a new custom "filename" label;
- hide the original `FilenameLabel`;
- implement the [`CurInstallProgressChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurInstallProgressChanged) to map the filename to anything you want to display and show it on the custom label.

```
[Files]
Source: "data1.dat"; DestDir: {app}
Source: "data2.dat"; DestDir: {app}
Source: "data3.dat"; DestDir: {app}
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  MyFilenameLabel: TNewStaticText;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  MyFilenameLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  { Clone the FilenameLabel }
  MyFilenameLabel.Parent := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Parent;
  MyFilenameLabel.Left := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Left;
  MyFilenameLabel.Top := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Top;
  MyFilenameLabel.Width := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width;
  MyFilenameLabel.Height := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Height;
  MyFilenameLabel.AutoSize := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.AutoSize;

  { Hide real FilenameLabel }
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Visible := False;
end;

procedure MapFilename(var Filename: string; Physical, Personalized: string);
begin
  if CompareText(Filename, Physical) = 0 then Filename := Personalized;
end;

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
var
  Filename: string;
begin
  Filename := ExtractFileName(WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption);

  // Map filenames to descriptions
  MapFilename(Filename, 'data1.dat', 'Some hilarious videos');
  MapFilename(Filename, 'data2.dat', 'Some awesome pictures');
  MapFilename(Filename, 'data3.dat', 'Some cool music');

  MyFilenameLabel.Caption := Filename;
end;
```

[image: Description instead of filename]